# How to load test video stream with jmeter

Tags: jmeter, video-streaming, performance-testing, load-testing, blazemeter

I am using **Red5** server to stream videos in my application. I have **jmeter** for load testing and **blazemeter** chrome extension for recording scripts.

Somehow the media files(the video chunks) are not getting recorded into the jmx file. Is there a way to record these files using blazemeter or any other tool?

Once recorded how can we use the script to perform load test in jmeter?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you should be recording this type of traffic as it is something you won't be able to properly replay, moreover JMeter (and BlazeMeter) recorder is capturing only [HTTP](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP) requests

First of all you need to identify which protocol is being used for video transmission using your [browser developer tools](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/What_are_browser_developer_tools) or a sniffer tool like [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/), once you figure that out you should mimic browser traffic via:

- [WebSocket Samplers](https://bitbucket.org/pjtr/jmeter-websocket-samplers/src/master/) - if your server uses [WebSocket](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSocket)
- [HLS Plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/HLS-3.0-Release) - if your server uses [HTTP Live Streaming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Live_Streaming)
- etc.